# Delete old migrations differences

Tags: php, doctrine, migration, symfony1

How can I delete the old migrations differences? When doing  `doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` I get no problems, but when doing the `doctrine:migrate` I get problems. It seems as if doctrine is trying to migrate old stuff that doesnt "count" any longer ...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either delete the migration class or add the generate version table (can't remember the exact name) and set the value to the migration you want start from.

Comment: Where do I find this class or table?

Comment: Once you've run a migration, there will be a new table in that database. I think it called migration_version. It should have one column with one row. If you just change the value of the row to the migration before the one you want to run.

Comment: When you generate doctrine migrations it creates class files that extend Doctrine_Migration. If you just delete the migrations you don't want to run, then the won't run when you call doctrine:migrate. If you're using symfony, those migration class are in lib/migration.

Comment: I just deleted all the php files I could find inside migration/doctrine. Worked like a dream :)

Answer (score 8):

Just to complement the selected answer (from the documentation):

Adding a version:

```
./doctrine migrations:version YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --add
```

Deleting a version:

```
./doctrine migrations:version YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --delete
```

**The command does not execute any migrations code, it simply adds the specified version to the database.**

[More info](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations/2.0/docs/reference/managing-migrations/en)

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 5, the migrations are in the `src/Migrations` folder.

I found that locally I had deleted the bad migration, but on production the old Migrations files where still there even after a `git push`.

I also cleared the table (or migration) in the database in the table `migration_version`